Flow rate of a pipe divided into smaller pipes - calculating the time the flow takes
Water is flowing through a pipe at 15 liters per minute. The pipe is 20mm in diameter. It widens at a certain point and in the middle is an object that blocks the pipe but has holes that the water can flow through. The total cross sectional area of the holes is equal to the cross sectional area of the 20mm diameter section of the pipe.
I want to determine the flow velocity in these small holes.
I am assuming that the flow rate in one of the holes is equal to the flow rate in the 20mm diameter pipe divided by the number of holes. If this is correct, can we calculate the flow velocity using the formula of velocity equals flow area divided by flow rate?

Can you provide a sketch. please?

Short answer.
The principle of continuity for incompressible fluids, states that the flow rate $Q$ must be constant throughout the system. This means that the flow rate in the 20 mm diameter section of the pipe is the same as the total flow rate through all the holes.
Here is the complete answer which I’m sure you’ll easily follow and see that you were correct in your thinking.
First part of pipe:
Flow rate $Q = 15 \, \text{L/min}$. In (m³/s):
$$15 \, \text{L/min} = \frac{15 \times 10^{-3}}{60} \, \text{m³/s} = 2.5 \times 10^{-4} \, \text{m³/s}$$
Cross-section =  20 mm = 0.02 m. Cross-sectional area $A_{\text{pipe}}$ of the pipe is:
$$A_{\text{pipe}} = \frac{\pi d^2}{4} = \frac{\pi (0.02)^2}{4} \approx 3.14 \times 10^{-4} \, \text{m}^2$$
Water velocity by the continuity equation $Q = A \times v$, where $v_{\text{pipe}}$ is the flow velocity in the pipe:
$$v_{\text{pipe}} = \frac{Q}{A_{\text{pipe}}} = \frac{2.5 \times 10^{-4}}{3.14 \times 10^{-4}} \approx 0.796 \, \text{m/s}$$
Thus, water velocity in the 20 mm diameter section = $\approx$ 0.796 m/s.
Part of the pipe made up of holes.
The total cross-sectional area of the holes equals 20 mm, i.e., the same diameter as the previous section of the pipe. Hence, the total flow rate is still $Q$.
With $n$ holes, flow rate through each hole is $\frac{Q}{n}$.  Area of each hole = $A_{\text{hole}}$, velocity through each hole $v_{\text{hole}}$ would be:
$$v_{\text{hole}} = \frac{\frac{Q}{n}}{A_{\text{hole}}}$$
Since the total area of the holes equals the pipe's cross-sectional area:
$$n \times A_{\text{hole}} = A_{\text{pipe}}$$
We rearrange:
$$A_{\text{hole}} = \frac{A_{\text{pipe}}}{n}$$
Then substitute into the velocity equation:
$$v_{\text{hole}} = \frac{\frac{Q}{n}}{\frac{A_{\text{pipe}}}{n}} = \frac{Q}{A_{\text{pipe}}}$$
Velocity in each hole equals the velocity in the 20 mm pipe, $v_{\text{hole}} = 0.796 \, \text{m/s}$.
